# How to get DB2 driver load correctly on AIX 5.3

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, aix

I am having this annoying problem of loading DB2 driver from a JAVA application on AIX5.3, what I got is this :

java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: db2jdbc (A file or directory in the path name does not exist.)
        at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver.(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1243)
        at com.hp.sm.doctor.collection.commandLineConsole.CommandLineEntryMain.main(CommandLineEntryMain.java:143)

I googled a lot, seems I am all set with everything, but this exception won't go away..
Here are details:
**PATH**=/usr/java5/bin:/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/java14/jre/bin:/usr/java14/bin:/home/scuser/SC6283/RUN:/home/fpeSM/sqllib/bin:/home/fpeSM/sqllib/adm:/home/fpeSM/sqllib/misc
**CLASSPATH**=/home/fpeSM/sqllib/java/db2java.zip:/home/fpeSM/sqllib/java/db2jcc.jar:/home/fpeSM/sqllib/java/sqlj.zip:/home/fpeSM/sqllib/function:/home/fpeSM/sqllib/java/db2jcc_license_cu.jar:.
**LIBPATH**=/usr/lib:/lib:/home/fpeSM/sqllib/lib64

I run my script by

java -cp /home/fpeSM/sqllib/java/db2java.zip:/home/fpeSM/sqllib/java/db2jcc.jar:/home/fpeSM/sqllib/java/sqlj.zip:/home/fpeSM/sqllib/function:/home/fpeSM/sqllib/lib32:/home/fpeSM/sqllib/java/db2jcc_license_cu.jar:.:smdoctor.jar com.hp.sm.doctor.collection.commandLineConsole.CommandLineEntryMain

Can anyone tell me what's gist to make the whole thing work? Many many.. thanks!
P.S., libdb2jdbc.so DOES exist under /home/fpeSM/sqllib/lib64.

Even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try telling Java where the DB2 native libraries are located by adding `-Djava.library.path=/home/fpeSM/sqllib/lib64:...` to your command. Your PATH and CLASSPATH variables and command raises some questions:

- Why would you have two different versions of Java (1.4 and 5)
  available on the PATH?
- It seems two versions of the DB2 drivers are
  available on the CLASSPATH. `db2java.zip` provides the DB2 JDBC type 2 and 4
  drivers and `db2jcc.jar` provides the DB2 JDBC type 4 driver.  DB2
  did away with the type 2 JDBC driver somewhere around version late-8
  or early-9.
- Are 32-bit and 64-bit libraries installed?  If you're running 32-bit Java, make sure your
  library is a 32-bit library. I'm not familiar with AIX, but for Linux I would use `file libdb2jdbc.so` to check if it's a 32-bit or 64-bit library.

Answer (score 0):

Even,

1. what are the contents of db2java.zip file ?
2. Please unzip it and see it it has any jar files and native binaries. Put jar files in classpath and binaries in path.
3. If the zip contains only jar files, put all of those jar files in classpath.
4. Putting zip file in classpath will not put jars inside it in classpath. You will have put extract the jar files and put them in classpath.